# keyboard shortcut editor does not intercept keypresses

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I've been using suckless dwm for years and i really need to make the shortcuts look alike to feel at home ;)

On ubuntu oneiric, the keyboard shortcut editor is opened with: system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts.

The help in the window specifies: 'To edit a shortcut, click the row and hold down the new keys or press backspace to clear'

So I select the first row of the 'navigation' section and highlight 'Move window to workspace 1'

Then i hold down ctrl+alt+1 for ten seconds but nothing happens. The shortcut still appears as 'disabled'. I'm unable to set any shortcut, i've tried many combinations. For example, a combination with Super key will be intercepted by unity instead of being catched by the keyboard shortcut editor window.

Can anybody reproduce this with oneiric ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After "Navigation" from the left pane, click the "Disabled" label within the row. It will now change to "New Shortcut", now press your key combination, or Backspace to clear.

[image]